# use a state-machine for level advancing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, state-machine

Level by level quiz game:

I would like to have the user progress be saved and return to the appropriate level & step when clicked.  Does it make sense to use a state machine as the user advances levels?  A multi step form? Just javascript?

I am a bit confused as to whether I should just be digging into the state_machine gem or whether I should pursue a different path.  I truly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Railscast on State Machines:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines

Comment: Ty - for others reference I found: http://gistflow.com/posts/679-state-machine-with-rails-basics & http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyUK5RAJg1c